# Constructing Json values with double as data type

Tags: json

I am constructing a Json schema file which is read by my C# code on validating Json files. One of the property I used is something like this

```
 "XOSCLockTime": {
              "type": "double"
            }
```

and it works fine, but in order to handle null values we are suppose to do something like this

```
"XOSCLockTime": {
              "type": ["double", "null"]
            }
```

and this gives error saying double is not an acceptable value here?? What is wrong here?? Does for data type **double** null values are handled automatically??

this is a snap shot of my schema file

```
"TestStationSerialNumber": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "TestStationType": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "X": {
      "type": ["integer", "null"]
    },
```

here i replaced double with integer after i start getting error. if i put double i get this error on schema file" *Value is not accepted. Valid values: "array", "boolean", "integer", "null", "number", "object", "string"."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double` is not a type recognized by JSON schema. JSON schema defines the following [data types](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html): `string`, `number`, `integer`, `object`, `array`, `boolean` and `null`.

There are two [numeric types](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html): `integer` and `number`.

If your numbers are not integral numbers then `number` is the type you need.

Comment: but question is it is recogniged when used without null

Comment: This depends entirely on the implementation of the JSON schema validator.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the below two properties which would give you the expected result.
`minimum` and `maximum`

For example in our case we wanted to have longitude and latitude in double in Json schema so we had below schema definition:

```
"latitude": {
    "type": [
    "null",
    "number"
    ],
    "minimum": -90,
    "maximum": 90
},
"longitude": {
    "type": [
    "null",
    "number"
    ],
    "minimum": -180,
    "maximum": 180
}

and generated classed has below properties:

@Nullable
    private Double latitude;
@Nullable
    private Double longitude;
```